# incompatible pointer type in c pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int insert (struct node *head, int data);
int print (struct node *head);

int main()
{
    struct node *head;

    head = NULL;
    // printf("%d\n",head);
    insert(&head,5);
    insert(&head,4);
    insert(&head,6);
    print(&head);
    print(&head);
    print(&head);
}

int insert(struct node *head,int data) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->next = NULL;
        head->data = data;
        // printf("%d\n",data);
    }
    else {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        if(tmp->next!=NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp->next  = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp->next->next = NULL;
        tmp->next->data = data;
        // printf("%d\n",data);
    }
}

int print (struct node *head) {
    printf("hello entered here\n");
    struct node *tmp = head;

    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("entered null\n");
        return;
    }

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->next == NULL) {
            printf("%0d", tmp->data);
        } else {
            printf("%0d -> ", tmp->data);
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I got the following warning when i *compile* it

```
In function main:
insert.c:16: warning: passing argument 1 of insert from incompatible pointer type
insert.c:17: warning: passing argument 1 of insert from incompatible pointer type
insert.c:18: warning: passing argument 1 of insert from incompatible pointer type
insert.c:19: warning: passing argument 1 of print from incompatible pointer type
insert.c:20: warning: passing argument 1 of print from incompatible pointer type
insert.c:21: warning: passing argument 1 of print from incompatible pointer type
```

When i *run* it i will get following output

```
hello entered here
0 -> 5 -> 6
hello entered here
0 -> 5 -> 6
hello entered here
0 -> 5 -> 6
```

Please help me remove this warnings.
And can u also help me add a function to remove the node in C
What is the mistake I am doing?
Should i pass `**head` to the function?

Comment: did you try print(head); instead?

Comment: printf("%d",head) in main prints a 0

Answer (score 0):

Currently the functions print() and insert() expects to `struct node*` whereas you pass `struct node **`. If you want to pass a copy then drop the `&` in your function calls in your code.

If you want to modify the pointer `head` pass a pointer to pointer and modify the parameters accordingly:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>


    struct node {
      int data;
      struct node *next;
    };
    int insert (struct node **head, int data);
    int  print  (struct node **head);

    int main()
    {
     struct node *head;
     head = NULL;
    // printf("%d\n",head);
     insert(&head,5);
     insert(&head,4);
     insert(&head,6);
     print(&head);
     print(&head);
     print(&head);

    } 
    int  insert(struct node **head,int data){

      if(*head == NULL){
        *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->data = data;
    //    printf("%d\n",data);
      }
    else {
      struct node *tmp = *head;
      if(tmp->next!=NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
      }
    tmp->next  = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      tmp->next->next = NULL;
      tmp->next->data = data;
    //  printf("%d\n",data);
    }

    }


    int print (struct node **head) {
      printf("hello entered here\n");
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        if (*head == NULL) {
          printf("entered null\n");
            return;
        }
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            if (tmp->next == NULL) {
                printf("%0d", tmp->data);
            } else {
                printf("%0d -> ", tmp->data);
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: I want to pass only struct node *head everywhere I dont want to run it with **head

Comment: Hey whats the difference between *head and (*head).

Comment: You really want to use **head as you seem to want to modify the pointer `head`. `->` binds tighter than `*` so `*head->next` is `*(head->next)` whereas you want to use `(*head)->next`.
That's why it's necessary to have the brackets.

Comment: its not clear the diference between *head->next and (*head)->next. Can you explain in detail please

Comment: @kingsindian as per [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4(v=vs.71).aspx) isnt `*a->b` same as `(*a)->b` ?

Comment: @SuvP No. Notice that `->` is above the unary * in that table. `a->b` is same as `(*a).b` but not `*a->b`.

Comment: @RahulReddy Read about operator precedence & associativity in C. Try with small examples. You'll understand it yourself.

Comment: RahulReddy @Suvp See this example to see why it's not valid: http://ideone.com/Jf7eUR

Comment: @kingsindian Now, that my head is thinking clearly, I can see the absurdity of my question. I read your comment and I thought you are saying otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert()` smells - too complicated. This is some sort of OO actually.

Here is my way, direct typed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// class node_t
typedef struct __node_s *node_t; // Mind the pointer here.
struct __node_s {
    int data;
    node_t next;
};
node_t node_init(void); // Constructor.
void node_append(node_t, int);
void node_drop_last(node_t);
void node_print(node_t);
void node_fini(node_t); // Destructor.
// end class node_t

int main(void)
{
    node_t head = node_init();
    node_append(head, 5);
    node_append(head, 4);
    node_append(head, 6);
    node_print(head);
    node_drop_last(head);
    node_print(head);
    node_fini(head);
    head = NULL;
    return 0;
}

node_t node_init(void)
{
     node_t node = malloc(sizeof(struct __node_s));
     assert(node);
     memset(node, 0, sizeof(struct __node_s));
     return node;
}

void node_insert(node_t head, int data)
{
    node_t last = head, new = node_init();
    for (; last->next; last = last->next);
    new->data = data;
    last->next = new;
}

void node_drop_last(node_t head)
{
    node_t last = head;
    if (!head->next)
        return;
    for (; last->next->next; last - last->next);
    node_fini(last->next);
    last->next = NULL;
}

void node_print(node_t head)
{
    for (node_t this = head->next; this; this = this->next)
    {
        printf("%d", this->data);
        if (this->next)
            putchar(' '); // A lot faster!
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void node_fini(node_t head)
{
    if (head->next)
    {
        node_fini(head->next);
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    free(head);
}
```